# Passing a callback function with arguments coming from different components as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

I know the title is not extremely clear so maybe a simplified example would help.

I have a react component in charge of translations (the following is a super-simplified version):

```js
const data = {
  foo: {
    en: 'hello',
    es: 'hola'
  },
  bar: {
    en: 'world',
    es: 'mundo'
  }
  baz: {
    en: 'the answer is {PLACEHOLDER}',
    es: 'la respuesta es {PLACEHOLDER}'
  }
}

const Translation = ({strKey, param, lang}) => {
  const getTranslatedString = () => {
    const translation = data[strKey][lang]
    return (translation.indexOf('{PLACEHOLDER}') > -1 && param)
      ? translation.replace('{PLACEHOLDER}', param)
      : translation
  }
  
  return <p>getTranslatedString()</p>
}

Translation.defaultProps = {
  lang: 'en'
}

export default Translation;
```

I use it as follows:

```js
<Translation strKey='baz' param={42} /> // renders as <p>the answer is 42</p>
<Translation strKey='baz' param={42} lang='es' /> // renders as <p>la respuesta es 42</p>
```

Now I have to modify my `Translation` component so that I can pass to it a callback function to manipulate the translated string. This function need to take as input some arguments set in the parent component and the string set in the `Translation` component itself. Here is where I am getting stuck, as I am having troubles understanding how to handle the arguments coming from two different components:

```js
const data = {
  foo: {
    en: 'hello#world',
    es: 'hola#mundo'
  }
}

// utility string manipulation function that will be used as callback
function getStringChunk(str, index) {
  return str.split('#')[index];
}

// Modified `Translation` component
const Translation = ({strKey, param, lang, callback}) => {
  const getTranslatedString = () => {
    const translation = data[strKey][lang]
    return (translation.indexOf('{PLACEHOLDER}') > -1 && param)
      ? translation.replace('{PLACEHOLDER}', param)
      : translation
  }
  
  return <p>{callback ? callback(getTranslatedString()) : getTranslatedString()}</p> // `callback` could be any function with any number of additional arguments 
}

const ParentComponent = ({isFirst}) => {
  return (
    <Translation
      strKey='foo'
      callback={() => {
        const index = isFirst ? 0 : 1;
        getStringChunk(index) // the function expects a first `str` argument but that is set inside the Translation component itself
      }}
    /> // should render either <p>hello</p> or <p>world</p>, depending on the value of `isFirst`
  );
}
```

I am pretty sure there is something very fundamental and elementary I am missing, something that will make me feel as a complete idiot as soon as someone points out the solution, but I am having some kind of "mind block" and I am running in circles without finding a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you just pass isFirst as an argument to Translation and create the callback function there?

Comment: Because there are many different string manipulations you might want to perform; in the example I want to split a string and take only part of it, but in another component I might want to transform the string in CamelCase and in a third one I might want to perform yet a different string manipulation. If I define each possible manipulation inside `Translation`, the component can become very big and heavy very quickly.

Comment: if there are multiple possible callback functions you might make, will the string be the only argument that is passed to all of them from within Translation?

Comment: Exactly. What I am trying to achieve is a way of getting the translated string (as I've done until now) and manipulate it before returning it therefore the translated string would be the only argument that will _always_ be passed to the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like this

```
const ParentComponent = ({isFirst}) => {
  return (
    <div>
    <Translation
      strKey='foo'
      lang={'en'}
      callback={(mystr) => () => {
        const index = isFirst ? 0 : 1;
        return getStringChunk(mystr,index)
      }}
    /> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

we make a function that returns the callback function by taking a string.
then you could create the callback function as required inside Translation

`return <p>{callback ? callback(getTranslatedString())() : getTranslatedString()}</p>`

Comment: Yes, this did the trick; thank you very much